# By pass a proxy of my server for sending gmail

Tags: java, proxy, gmail-imap

The situation is:

I have a server where my code is hosted and this code for a particular servlet calls send a gmail message to some users. So I use the gmail smtp server to send my message across users.

The problem:
My server is at level 2 and at level 1 is the main server which has a proxy hosted on it. The problem is it redirects all requests from port 546 to the outside world. I would like to know if setting

```
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
```

is enough to send the mail or do I have to set any additional parameters to send the mail.

Right now with above settings I get an exception of

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com
```

Furhter I would like to add that when I do the nslookup for smtp.gmail.com, I get a

```
 *** Can't list domain smtp.gmail.com: Unspecified error
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What have you set in your browser in order to access internet through that proxy ? you have to set the same kind of settings as I mentioned before

Comment: yes same settings for the browser for all protocols with a server name and the port number under the LAN settings for the IE and Network settings under Mozilla

Answer (score 0):

This is a DNS problem not a proxying problem. Your DNS is set to not deliver that IP address to you. Talk to your netadmin.